# Windows not accepting Socket Connections when running as service

Tags: python, windows, sockets, service, netcat

I´m writing a small application on Windows 10 in Python.
It should listen on TCP socket connections and receive some data. No Responses are required from the application. Application must be runned as a windows service.
When running in Debug Mode it works perfectly. It receives the data, and processes it.
When running as a Service (with pyinstaller and pywin32 packages) no data is received and nothing happens.

```py
def sockThread(port: int, interface: str):
    global sock 
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind((interface, port))
    except socket.error as e:
       logging.error('could not open socket connection with' + interface + ":" + str(port))
       logging.error('error: ' + str(e))
       return
    
    
    logging.info("socket timeout: " + str(sock.gettimeout()))
    
    #run:
    while stop==False:
        logging.info("socketthread starting, listening on:" + interface + ":" + str(port))
        try:
            sock.listen(1)
            c, addr = sock.accept()
            #logging.info("socketthread connection accepted")
        except socket.error as e:
            logging.error('error while listening to socket:' + str(e))
        else:
            data = c.recv(2048)
            #logging.info("data received: " + str(data))
            processStarter.startSubProcess(data)
    logging.error("socket thread leaving")
```

Code is tested with a Raspberry Pi command line:
`netcat -w1 192.168.178.27 60000 <testfile.txt`

Is  there any difference in the configuration of a Windows Service and Application?

Comment: What error was logged? NB You only need to `listen()` once, after the `bind()`. Not inside the loop. The 2nd and subsequent `listen()` calls will fail, as your logging must have shown.

Comment: I need to listen in a loop, because clients send data not only once. I don´t want to reopen the socket each time. 
No errors  logged as  a service and no connections  as a service. Working a expected, when in Debug Mode with a separate Main method

Comment: No, you do *not* need to `listen()` in a loop, because that's not how you use the Sockets API. Your error logging should have shown you that already. Have you checked it? You need to *accept* in a loop.

Comment: Ok, so the call to listen method shoud be moved  outside in front of the  loop? No errors:
INFO:root:socket timeout: None
INFO:root:socketthread starting, listening on:192.168.178.27:60000
Edit:  Ok I found a possible  root of an error. Let me  fix the config file

Comment: Corrected the listen() call, checked configuration once again. No changes, no Errors, in Service Mode. No output

Comment: Me: "You only need to `listen()` once, after the `bind()`. Not inside the loop. ". You: "I need to listen in a loop." Me: "No, you do not need to `listen()` inside a loop." You: "Ok, so the call to listen method should be moved outside in front of the loop?" Please.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I´m very resistant to understand what other try to say me

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to "Windows not accepting connections": Windows Firewall Rules are different for a Service and an Application inside Debugger.
So there are still some bugs in my Code, but the connections are now accepted now, when running as a Service.

Answer (score -2):

A Windows Service has to have specifically registered port to listen on.

The command is:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:PORT/
```

More on `add urlacl` is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/http/add-urlacl

Comment: 1. No it doesn't. 2. Your link is about URLs, not ports,. 3. it is about reserving, not registering. 4. It contains nothing that supports the claim in your first sentence.